# Delete lines with date out of pre-defined dates

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to delete the lines which are not in between the pre-defined range (March). I think the problem is somehow the numberformat. Any suggestion?

> ```
> frdatum = Format("01/03/2014", "dd/mm/yyyy")
> tdatum = Format("30/03/2014", "dd/mm/yyyy")
>
> valami = Format(frdatum, "dd/mm/yyyy")
> valami2 = Format(tdatum, "dd/mm/yyyy")
>
> Dim LValue As String
>
>
> finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
>
> Range("C2:C" & finalrow).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
>
>
> For i = finalrow To 2 Step -1
>     If Not valami < Format(Cells(i, 3).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy") < valami2 Then
>         Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
>     End If
> Next i
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare values which are **strings** as though they are **numbers**  Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()

    Dim frdatum As Date
    Dim tdatum As Date
    Dim LValue As String
    Dim d As Date

    frdatum = DateSerial(2015, 3, 1)
    tdatum = DateSerial(2015, 3, 31)

    finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("C2:C" & finalrow).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"


    For i = finalrow To 2 Step -1
        d = Cells(i, 3).Value
        If d > tdatum Or d < frdatum Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```